# UK Cyber Essentials compliance

Tags: linux, security

We are a small software company looking to get Cyber Essentials certification. The company consists entirely of developers working remotely, mostly using Linux machines.

We've trawled through all the questions and the guidance notes and sure enough it's all written from the Microsoft perspective. It also not always clear what's actually required and what can just be written policy.

Does anybody have any experience with getting a Linux setup certified for Cyber Essentials?

The biggest obstacle appears to be the requirement for the ability to remotely wipe machines. Secondary to that is technical controls to enforce password policies, regular updates, etc.

The path of least resistance would appear to be to use Ubuntu Pro which specifically lists CyberEssentials compliance. However we would far rather stick with vanilla Debian - is there any "standard" open source solution that would allow us to comply without having to switch to a corporate Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0):

No direct experience, but you presumably have central account & package management already sorted? So it shouldn't be wildly difficult to have the system check for instructions from your own management end-point (a website, if necessary), and download/validate them before executing them.

One of these commands could be a remote wipe script (if you're using LUKS, data dropped from `/dev/urandom` over the LUKS header would be sufficient)